# Проблема с горячими клавишами electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

В electron-приложении я использую `globalShortcut`. Но проблема в том, что зарегистрированные шорткаты не работают в другой программе, пока работает мое. Могу ли я это как-то обойти?

Answer (score 0):

Я не эксперт в этом API, но если там можно также отписываться от горячих клавиш, можно добавить обработку события на дефокус страницы и включать горячие клавиши только тогда, когда у пользователя открыто твое приложение. Точно не уверен, что возможно будет это реализовать, но я бы попробовал сделать так.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно, чтобы горячие клавиши срабатывали одновременно. И в моей, и в другой

Comment: Понял, тогда даже не знаю. Нужно подумать. Могу только посоветовать полазить в документации, иногда они разбирают некоторые проблемы.